# tezbridge plugin could not be detected in your browser

Tags: error

https://github.com/stove-labs/workshop-notarization/tree/dev/ui

I'm trying to set the repo up and make it run, but I would come across the error mentioned on title when I execute `yarn test`.

Things I tried:

1. Make sure both taquito and tezbridge installed.
2. I inserted the script of ·< src="https://www.tezbridge.com/plugin.js">· to the head of the ./public/index.html
3. I configured the signer (currently I select alice as the signer) on https://www.tezbridge.com/index.html?signer.
4. As the sandbox is running on localhost:8732, I reset the network to "http://localhost:8732" on the webpage too.

It seems my guesses are all wrong.  The error persists.  Would anyone lend a hand?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for checking out the notarization workshop! Try running the UI directly by ‘npm run start’ instead. I suspect the ‘public/index.html’ may not be used in the test suite for the UI - which we haven’t touched for the workshop itself

Comment: Thank you Matej.  I tried 'npm run start' and encountered another error.  It seems something wrong with the ts-loader according to the error msg.  "../sdk/src/tezos-notary-sdk.ts 10:14
Module parse failed: The keyword 'public' is reserved (10:14)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.".  Does it mean I need to edit the webpack.config.js under config folder?  I'm not very familar with js or react or anything, so spare me if this question is dumb. :)

Comment: problem fixed by replace with a newly downloaded ui folder and compile everything from the start.